# Detecting browser tab closure in Bokeh

Tags: bokeh

I want to detect if the user closes the browser tab that my application is running in. If this happens, I want to shut down a connected physical device. I'd like the sequence of events to be: user closes the browser tab (or browser), callback function is triggered, callback function closes device.

I'm using the Bokeh Server to serve an application. I don't use CustomJS at all.

Ideally, I'm looking for some kind of callback function (something like on_browser_close). I can't find anything in document or session that might do.

Is there a way of detecting that the browser (tab) has been closed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to make use of `on_session_destroyed`, which is described in [Lifecycle Callbacks](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#lifecycle-hooks). In a "Directory Format" Bokeh application, add a module `server_lifecyle.py`:

```
# server_lifecyle.py

def on_session_destroyed(session_context):
    # called when a session is closed (e.g. tab closed or time out)
```

Comment: I had a re-think about my problem and reformulated it, but I'm marking this as the solution because it would have solved my problem as was. Thank you bigreddot.